# Проверка вхождения символов в ячейку таблицы

Tags: python, pandas

Похожий вопрос был описан ранее [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1363343/Проверка-вхождения-слов-в-список-ячейки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1363343/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8)
Можете подсказать как изменить код если нужно не полное совпадение слова а только его части.

```
mapping = {"мелодрама": "marriage", "фантастика": "future", "сказка": "tale"}

# регулярные выражения для замены целых строк 
pat = {fr".*\b{v}\b.*": k for k, v in mapping.items()}

# создаем новый столбец при помощи замены строк
df["test"] = df["keywords"].replace(pat, regex=True)

# создаем "boolean mask" для строк из категории "другое"
mask = ~df["test"].isin(mapping.keys())

# заменяем строки по маске на "другое"
df.loc[mask, "test"] = "другое"
```

Comment: В какой именно части? Выделите из слов корни или иные фрагменты и ищите по ним. Ограничители `\b` тогда нужно убрать из регулярки

Comment: Часть слова может быть любая. В моем случае это закодированное сообщение. Пример St.zp st:стандартный zp:зарплата. Вот мне нужно в отдельную колонку вывести мапинг Стандартный и зарплата соответственно

Comment: Буква тоже часть слова. В вашем примере есть буква **а**, например, причем в обоих случаях. Какой по ней маппинг?

Comment: Мапинг будетдет только сочетание слов.

Comment: вы бы и писали в вопросе про проблему с вашими конкретными данными, а не какой-то абстрактный маппинг в сферическом вакууме.